# How to solve error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/app/Activity" while running gradle command "android" (javafxports)?

Tags: android, javafx, java-8, noclassdeffounderror, javafxports

Today I started looking at JavaFXPorts.
I read [this](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/5.0.1/#intellij-plugin) Gluon Documentation.

But... when I run the Step 2.4.3 ("Deploying the project") by clicking on application→run at gradle panel, the first error appeared:

```
com.gluonhq.charm.down.Platform <clinit>
javafx.platform is not defined. Desktop will be assumed by default.
```

As I run other->android at gradle panel (I wanted to package it to an apk first, I will attach device if it start working properly)
another error appeared:

```
Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/app/Activity
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.app.Activity
```

I am new at JavaFXPorts, as I told at the top.

Can anyone help? Anyone experienced this error too??

Greets
MatsG23 :)

The Code (I haven't changed it since project creation)
I selected "Gluon Mobile - Single View Project"

Main-Class

```java
public class Test extends MobileApplication {
    public void init() {
        addViewFactory(HOME_VIEW, BasicView::new);
    }
    public void postInit(Scene scene) {
        Swatch.BLUE.assignTo(scene);

        ((Stage) scene.getWindow()).getIcons().add(new 
        Image(Test.class.getResourceAsStream("/icon.png")));
    }
}
```

BasicView-Class

```java
public class BasicView extends View {
    public BasicView() {
        Label label = new Label("Hello JavaFX World!");
        Button button = new Button("Change the World!");
        button.setGraphic(new Icon(MaterialDesignIcon.LANGUAGE));
        button.setOnAction(e -> label.setText("Hello JavaFX Universe!"));
        VBox controls = new VBox(15.0, label, button);
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        setCenter(controls);
    }
    protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
        appBar.setNavIcon(MaterialDesignIcon.MENU.button(e -> System.out.println("Menu")));
        appBar.setTitleText("Basic View");
        appBar.getActionItems().add(MaterialDesignIcon.SEARCH.button(e -> System.out.println("Search")));
    }
}
```

**Device Information**

OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Home

Build: 10.0.18363 Build 18363

Computer: Dell Inspiron 15-3567

RAM: 8 GB

Core: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz[Cores 2] [Logical/Core 2]

Comment: Have you installed the Android SDK? Did you set the ANDROID_HOME path? Verify these steps from this more recent guide: https://docs.gluonhq.com/getting-started/#android-support. Also run `gradlew --info android`, and see a more detailed stacktrace.

Comment: yes, I have set the ANDROID_HOME in PATH Var. Here is the output of gradlew --info: https://pastebin.com/H7248SR5

Comment: Do you have something like `C:\Users\mats2\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar`?

Comment: yes this exists, exactly this path you wrote

Comment: @JoséPereda oh I solved it. there was an file gradle-wrapper.properties. I didn't know much about gradle until now. it seems like he is using different gradle.properties. Everywhere it was saying: hey there is a gradle.properties in folder .gradle in your user home - **but it was in project folder**